# Grep to count number of occurrences

Tags: linux, grep

I am new to Linux and have a CSV file (example below). I need to determine the number of Asian females there are. I tried running the following command as I am trying to determine the unique ethnicity count, but can't seem to get it right. Any help is appreciated! Desired output: 2 Asian Females

```
grep “Asian”, ‘,’ filename.csv | sort | uniq -c
```

| Year | Ethnicity | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2001 | White | Female |
| 2001 | Asian | Female |
| 2001 | White | Male |
| 2001 | Hispanic | Male |
| 2001 | Asian | Female |

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the contents of the `csv` file instead of providing a table. Also use proper quotes in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Update

```bsh
grep -F Asian filename.csv | grep -F -c Female
```

quoted from `man grep`:

```
-c, --count
             Only a count of selected lines is written to standard output.
```

Thanks to @terdon.

---

```bsh
grep -F Asian filename.csv | grep -F Female | wc -l
```

- `grep -F` - Interpret pattern as a set of fixed strings.
- `wc -l` - Print the number of lines.

Comment: Why would you want `-F` here?

Comment: @terdon Because fixed string matching is always faster than re_format regular expression pattern matching.

Comment: Hmm, fair point, yes. Although I really doubt that would be relevant in something as simple as this. Especially for the second `grep`. But fair enough. If you want speed though, you really want `grep -c` instead of a third pipe.

Comment: I am a fan of "simple is good". Using `grep` twice isn't a problem because it just follows UNIX philosophy and easier to read, besides we don't really need regular expression in this case.

Comment: I didn't know `-c` option before, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try `grep -c`:

```
printf '%d Asian Females\n' $(grep -c ',Asian,Female$' filename.csv)
```

Comment: Possibly better with GNU `grep`: `printf '%d Asian Females\n' $(grep -Pc ',\s*Asian\s*,\s*Female\s*$' filename.csv)`, or any `grep`: `printf '%d Asian Females\n' $(grep -c ',[[:blank:]]*Asian[[:blank:]],[[:blank:]]*Female[[:blank:]]*$' filename.csv)`.

Comment: If it's a `csv` any more complicated, I would prefer `csvgrep` or pythons or perls `csv` module

Answer (score 0):

One way among many:

```
echo "$(grep 'Asian' filename.csv | grep -c 'Female') Asian Females"
```

Comment: @c200402 What shell are you using? Are you sure `filename.csv` is the right file? A slightly better modification to the answer here is `echo "$(grep -i 'Asian' filename.csv | grep -ic 'Female') Asian Females"`

Answer (score 0):

```
k="Asian"
w="Female"

awk -v k="$k" -v w="$w" '$0 ~ k && $0 ~ w{count ++}END{print count,k,w"s"}' file.txt
```

output

```
2 Asian Females
```

Answer (score 0):

In most cases it is no good idea to use `grep` to search in CSV files, because `grep` searches in the whole line instead of the column, you want to search for.

But you can easily create a simple Perl script, which allows you to search with a SQL statement in CSV files.

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl
use DBI;
$dbh = DBI->connect ("dbi:CSV:")
    or die "Cannot connect: $DBI::errstr";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare (shift);
$sth->execute (@ARGV);
$result = $sth->fetchall_arrayref;
$sth->finish;
$dbh->disconnect;
print map { join (',', @$_) . "\n" } @$result;
```

The first argument is the SQL query and the remaining arguments are the arguments for the query. Example:

```
./csv.pl 'select * from example.csv where Ethnicity = ? and Gender = ?' Asian Female
```

Next you can use `count` to get the number:

```
./csv.pl 'select count(*), Ethnicity, Gender from example.csv where Ethnicity = ? and Gender = ?' Asian Female
```